# Universal variable can't be read in internal function of socket.on() in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

The `myChat` is a state in react and it is set universally. Here in `console.log(NEW)` it is being displayed but in NEW 2 it is not. I cant access it in the `socket.on()` the message is being received to the user but I can't access my chat in the the function

Client side

```
  const socketNewMessage = ()=>{
    if(user){
      console.log("NEW", myChat)
    socket.on('message received', (message)=>{
        console.log("NEW 2", myChat)
        if(message.msgRecieved.chatId === message.chatDetail._id){
          addMessage({
            ID : message.msgRecieved._id,
            type : "message" 
          })
        }
        if(message.msgRecieved.chatId !== message.chatDetail._id){
          //give notification
        }
        eraseUnreadMsg(user.userID, message.msgRecieved.chatId)
    })
    }
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    socketNewMessage()
    if(user && socketConnected){
      socket.on('typing', ()=>setTyping(true))
      socket.on('stop typing',()=>setTyping(false))  
    }
  })
```

Server side

```
    socket.on('new message', (msgRecieved, chatDetail)=>{
        var senderId = msgRecieved.senderId
        chatDetail.members.forEach(member => {
            if(senderId === member) return;
            let msg = {chatDetail,msgRecieved}
            socket.in(member).emit("message received", msg )
        }
        )
    })
```

I tried various approaches of passing it to the function `socketNewMessage()` but it is not working any way. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you subscribed to event `message received` the value `myChat` was null , if the value of `myChat` got updated some where  the event wont have that value. may be try subscribing to the event when you have the value of `myChat`

Comment: But at no position myChat is being changed when the event message received occurs

Comment: then how are you passing or setting the value in myChat?

Comment: It is being set when a chat is being opened. Otherwise no change

Comment: it took sometime to set that value to that variable .... you must be passing that as prop /parameter ...try using that directly .

Comment: But if that is case console.log("NEW",myChat) shouldn't have given any output but it does

Comment: try logging like this console.log("NEW",JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myChat))).... 

plus try using a hard coded value in place of myChat and check this issue still occurs

Comment: Yes it still does as myChat is not defined there so it gives error while JSON operation and I have tried hard coded method also.